# Realm Function - "We ran into an issue trying to start User Search"

Tags: realm, realm-object-server

So I hit the green "Play" button to run my Realm function and I'm getting this error. I was building a realm function for user search last night and at one point it randomly started giving me that error. Nothing is showing up in the logs. If I click on "Create New Function" and immediately run the pre-built one, I still get the same error. I also tried restarting the ROS but to no avail. Any ideas?

Edit -
The log tab in the ROS sidebar does not display anything but the Console Log underneath the realm function says “Opened function log: 48aaee7c-b70c-4111-ad2f-fbb44dccad8a”.

Versioning:

ROS V1.8.1, centOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Realm Object Server to 1.8.2 fixed the weirdness with Realm Functions and logs not appearing in the logs tab.